# Download a video from external link in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys I want to download videos from an external link
I have a field in database and this is video link.
I wrote :

```
return response()->download(url()->to($video->path));
```

but it gives me this error: 
Download File ERROR MESSAGE =  The file http://example.com/video_link" does not exist

while when I wrote this link in address bar in browser it shows video correctly to me.
How I can download a video with external link very fast ?

Comment: The `download` response expects a local file. It does not work with remote URLs.

Answer (score 0):

No unfortunately they didnt solve my problem. when I wrote this code:

```
$filename = $video->video_id;
$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $filename);
copy($video->path, $tempFile);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = ".$filename);
header("X-Accel-Redirect: ".$filename);
return response()->download($tempFile, $filename);
```

I got 504 nginx error :(